# Xamarin Archive tool - Seemingly normal error but unknown cause

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Today, for no reason that I can determine, my Android builds started showing this error below whenever I try to archive them:

`Please ensure that you are using a release configuration and that the "Use Shared Mono Runtime" option in your project's build options is unchecked.`

I have, of course, ensured that the "Use Shared Runtime" (that's the closest thing to the error message) option is unchecked. I am also using the same exact Release configuration that has successfully built and archived for months, including last week.

All that said, has anyone else encountered this error and know of a way around it?

Things I have tried:

- Clean, rebuild, archive.
- Clean, close VS, delete bin/obj, re-open, rebuild, archive.
- Clean, reboot machine, delete bin/obj, re-open VS, rebuild archive.
- Revert to previous app code, #1-3.
- Give up, Google It, find nothing, ask Xamarin.
- Get impatient. Ask SO.

Any ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: Are you archiving in RELEASE mode?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same exact Release configuration that we've used for months.

Comment: Well, while that message might have been because of archiving in debug mode, which you said it's not, then try deleting .vs folder in your solution folder as another option.

Comment: Ah. Good idea. That's one I haven't tried yet.

Comment: @Vahid You should post that as an answer. I deleted the .vs + all bin/obj (again) and 'lo and behold it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you've already tried many common options, **deleting .vs directory** can fix some strange and unknown IDE behaviors.

Comment: Deleting the .vs directory turned out to be exactly what I needed to do. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help.