# Archiving of the apk not successful

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk, archive

I'm generating the .apk file of my app. For that I'm archiving my android project. But the archiving is just loading it is not creating apk  also it doesn't show any error. I don't know what is the issue. You can see the screenshot.
[The archiving of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdB6Z.png) I have no issue with my build and my build is successful and also my pc is not at all slow so why it is still loading. Also I checked use shared runtime is unchecked in android options.

Comment: Is your project in release mode?

Comment: yes it is in release mode

Comment: How can I see the log of this archive process?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534351/xamarin-archive-tool-seemingly-normal-error-but-unknown-cause/50535650#50535650)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete **".vs" hidden folder** in your solution and then rebuild again.

Answer (score 0):

when you are in release mode you need to untick use shared runtime for faster deployment